# Google Map not showing up API V3 or showing up very slowly

Tags: google-maps, backbone.js, google-maps-api-3, backbone-views

I'm having a heck of a time trying to get a basic Google Map to show up. I've been on Stack Overflow for hours and haven't had any success so far. The closest I've gotten is the map loads 1/4 of a square, the top left quarter. But then if you try to drag, zoom, etc it just turns grey like the rest of the map. On a few occasions, with the same code, the map will load fully but only after a long time (not sure exactly how long, but > 5 minutes).

In my template I have

```
    <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

And then in my backbone view

```
  $.getScript('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=gMapsCallback')                
  window.gMapsCallback = function(){                                         
           var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
           var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: myLatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
           };
           var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
                mapOptions);                       
  }
```

Any ideas what might be happening? I am also open to any suggestions on a superior way to load a google map into a backbone view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, turns out there were a number of issues, including embedding a map in a Bootstrap tab, not including a callback, defining the div height and width, setting a small delay to load the map, and setting css attributes for the map. Oi. My final solution turned out to be:

In the template

```
<script src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=gMapsCallback'></script>
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

In the stylesheet

```
#map img {
  max-width: none;
}
#map label { 
  width: auto; display:inline; 
}
```

In the Backbone View

```
setTimeout(function(){
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.1, -2.44); 
                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 8,
                    center: myLatlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
                    mapOptions);   
                // Create marker 
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(53.1, -2.44),
                    title: 'The armpit of Cheshire'
                });

                // Add circle overlay and bind to marker
                var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                    map: map,
                    radius: 10000,    // metres
                    fillColor: '#AA0000'
                });
                circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
                map.setZoom( map.getZoom() );
            }, 100);
```

Painful. Notice that when I call the gmaps script I had to include the callback even though I never use it. Without it, it didn't work fully. No clue why.