# Backbone and Google Maps not showing

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm just getting started with backbone and actually stuck with the task of showing a Google map, here's the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>wePadel!</title> 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

    <style>
      html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
      }

      #map_container {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #e2a1c6;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body> 

    <a href="#map">Map</a>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="map_container"></div>
        <ul id="matchlisting"></ul>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.8.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>


    <script src="routers/router.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="models/match-model.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="views/match-view.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="views/map-view.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="helpers/helpers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Routers.js

```
app = {
    helpers: {},
    models : {},
    views  : {},
    routers: {},
    init: function(){
        mainView = new app.views.Matches();
        appRouter = new app.routers.Router();
        Backbone.history.start();
    }
}

app.routers.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "":     "mainView",             //#main
        "map":      "mapView"
    },

    mainView: function(){
        new app.views.Matches();
    },

    mapView: function(){
        new app.views.Map();
    }
});
```

And the mapView

```
app = app || {};

app.views.Map = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function(){
        self = this;
        self.configMap();
            self.render();
    },

    configMap: function(){
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_container'),
          mapOptions);
    },

    render: function(){
        return this;
    }

});
```

I can see the map object when debugging but nothing is displayed within the map_container div, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've seen other examples, some of them had document.getElementById and others jQuery elements, I've tried with both approaches but neither worked for me.

Comment: The map constructor definitely wants a element, not a jQuery object. When you say you can see the map object, do you mean that it is contained in `#map_container`? If so, the issue is probably that you have not specified a height/width for the `#map_container` div.

Comment: I just edited the text with my last tests, changed the jQuery object for the element, and modified the css with a background-color in order to see whether the height was 0 or not, sadly the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found where the problem was, after searching stackoverflow intensively I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970467/google-map-not-showing-up-api-v3-or-showing-up-very-slowly).

Basically I had to change my call to google map's API and append "&callback=gMapsCallback" at the end of the call, so where I was doing:

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
```

I had to do this even though I'm not using the callback

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&callback=gMapsCallback"></script>
```

and now the map is showing.

Hope this helps somebody else!.
Thank you all.